# Use a precomputed array or a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, optimization

What's faster when compiling with GCC in C++,

using a precompute array of 2 columns and 300 rows,

or using a third grade polynomial, such as `"x^3 + x^2 + x + 40"`?

(Sorry for my english)

Edit:

Is faster searching in an array, (Input value the first column and output the second column.)
or using a function (The input and output of the polynomial is obvious)?

edit2:

**using index**

Comment: You should provide more examples to make your question more clear. How is  `x^3 + x^2 + x + 40` related to the array?

Comment: what example ? it's all theoretical

Comment: If you evaluate the polynomial millions of times, the cost will be higher than creating the table once. If you evaluate the polynomial 100 times or less, then it's not worth creating the table. You have to decide at what point creating the table starts to pay off.

Comment: Your English is fine. It's not the reason nobody understands your question.

Comment: @RSahu And of course, it depends whether you generate the table off-line, or in a constructor of a static variable.  If the program is short, and invoked a lot, it's sometimes worth generating the table off line, and compiling it in to use static initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he is trying to compare the speed between a polynomial computation and a lookup table.

It depends. The lookup table is usually stored in memory and the LD instruction will be involved. If the lookup table is not cached then expect long delay from memory.

If you need to access the lookup table frequently and for multiple times, and the table is of reasonable size, try to use lookup table. it is because, very likely, the table will be cached. If you were able to store the table on stack, then do it. Since the data on stack are more likely to be cached than the data on heap.

On the other hand, if the calculation is not frequent, then using polynomial computation is fine. This can save you some memory and make your code more readable.

Comment: that's what I was asking. thanks :)

Comment: No it's not. Searching for value will take more time than few multiplications and additions. The table has chance only, if you store exactly the values for arguments you will call and do no perform a search.

Comment: @luk32: I think he is just trying to access the lookup table like an array using the index, no search is needed.

Comment: Well OP wrote "*Is faster **searching** in an array, or using a function ?*", so I dunno.

Comment: sorry yeah. I use index

Comment: @user3199553:  Since the polynomial is small and simple to calculate, the only definite method to determine which algorithm is faster is to profile.  The execution speed may be platform dependent and the difference between the two methods may be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Computing a 3rd grade polynomial will nearly always be faster.

People seem to forget they need to search a value in this "look-up" table. Which is `O(log N)`.

Evaluating polynomial of 3rd grade is trivial enough, that the table would need to be uselessly small to outperform it.

The table has chance only, if you store exactly the values for arguments you will look for and you know where in the table the reside. So you do not have to perform a search. That would make it a real look-up table, and it would probably be faster.

The example I know where tables are indeed used are computing sine function with high precision (more on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table#Computing_sines)). Although, there computation would be really expensive.

Comment: so the 3rd grade polynomial would be "O(1)" ?

Comment: Yes by definition. It would need to be extremely long computations to take more time than a search.

Comment: @luk32: if I understand him correctly. He just wants to use an array and use the index to access it. So no search is needed.

Comment: @user3199553 By OPs comment under your answer I think you are wrong. I am not sure what OP needs and I don't dare to interpret. I am answering the question he asked, while indicating when table would be faster.

Comment: @luk32: Well, your answer is pretty good and I like it. But I'm not sure if "i think you are wrong" is a typo... When we are referring to a lookup table, usually no search will be performed. This sentence is from Wiki: "In computer science, a lookup table is an array that replaces runtime computation with a simpler array indexing operation." And that is why I use the term "lookup table" in my answer. Anyway, both answers are good and there's no point to guess OP's original intention :)

Comment: @user3199553 Well I should put, the look-up into quotation marks. Please note later I used only "table". I am aware what look-up table really is. I just didn't take enough care to word everything properly. The real problem is where the table is actually a look-up or nor. I think it's not, that is what I meant. I just noticed OP edited the comment, from "search" to "index" =) I was quite important. I am glad we're clear. =)

Answer (score 1):

You should actually profile the code.

**Polynomial Evaluation**
The function is:

```
int Evaluate_Polynomial(int x)
{
  register const int term1 = x * x * x;
  register const int term2 = x * x;
  register const int result = term1 + term2 + x + 40;
  return result;
}
```

*Note:  In the above function, `register` is used to remind the compiler to use registers, even in the unoptimized version (a.k.a. debug).*

Without optimization, the above function has 3 multiply operations and 3 addition operations, for a total of 6 data processing operations (not including load or store).

**Table Lookup**
The function is:

```
int Table_Lookup_Polynomial(int x)
{
  int result = 0;
  if ((x < 0) || (x > 300))
  {
    result = table[x];
  }
  else
  {
    // Handle array index out of bounds
  }
  return result;
}
```

In the above example, there is a possibility of 3 comparisons (jumps) and a pointer dereference.  Verify importantly, there is a need for error handling.

**Summary**
The polynomial version may contain more instructions, but they are data processing instructions and can be easily *inlined*.  They do not cause a processor's instruction cache to be reloaded.

The table lookup needs to perform boundary checking.  The boundary checking will cause the processor to pause and maybe reload the instruction pipeline, which takes time.  The error checking and handling may cause issues during maintenance if the range is ever changed.

The functions should be profiled to verify which algorithm is faster.  The loss of time due to altering the execution flow may be longer than the pure math data processing functions of the polynomial evaluation.

The compiler may be able to use special processor functions to make the polynomial evaluation faster.  For example, the ARM7 processor has instructions that can perform a multiply and add together.

Comment: So your suggestion, is to make a test and see if the processor makes the polynomial evaluations faster than the lookup ?

Comment: @AlejandroMorais:  Yes, write a function that performs the polynomial evaluations.  Start the clock, then call the function 100,000 times, the retrieve ending time.  Divide the difference by 100,000.  Perform similar test with the lookup table.  You may need more iterations depending on the resolution of the timing or clock.